# How to properly administrate a database using a script

Tags: python, kubernetes

I use a python script to insert data in my database (using pandas and sqlalchemy). The script read from various sources, clean the data and insert it in the database. I plan on running this script once in a while to completely override the existing database with more recent data.

At first I wanted to have a single service and simply add an endpoint that would require higher privileges to run the script. But in the end that looks a bit odd and, more importantly, that python script is using quite a lot of memory (~700M) which makes me wonder how I should configure my deployment.

Increasing the memory limit of my pod for this (once in a while) operation looks like a bad idea to me, but I'm quite new to Kubernetes, so maybe I'm wrong. Thus this question.

So what would be a good (better) solution? Run another service just for that, simply connect to my machine and run the update manually using the python script directly?

Comment: We need a lot more details on this problem. As this is written now, you can find 1000 different possible solutions. All from e.g. using Kafka and queues to synchronous jobs...

Comment: I can add many details. You need details on the long term constraints/goals I have or details about the script and data?

Answer (score 2):

**To run on demand**
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/.
This generates a `Pod` that runs till completion (exit) only once - a `Job`.

**To run on schedule**
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/.
Every time when hitting a schedule, this generates the new, separate `Job`.

Comment: The `Job` solution looks to be a good solution, on the other hand I tried it and it seems the task (and associated pods) stay alive even after termination of the task (I tried with a simple `ls` for a start). I tried using `spec.ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 0` and `spec.activeDeadlineSeconds: 100` but none seems to have any effect. Should the task send a system signal to notify termination or failure?

Comment: A process inside should exit with an appropriate exit code, this will be a signal. Make sure you override the container `entrypoint`, or `command`, with a task you need to.

Comment: Here's an example implementation https://cloudnativedevopsblog.com/posts/database-migrations/

Comment: For my first tests I simply used `command: ["ls"]`. (I'm running this locally on minikube, maybe there is a problem with minikube itself?).

Comment: Here is my [test yaml file](https://gist.github.com/cglacet/4e4d28facad1ac09eaa6e0fabb0a47ee)

Comment: I tried on my minikube and it worked: `k get job
NAME   COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
test   1/1           7s         27s`. I'm also able to list pods, and check the logs of the underlying job pod (the ls output) with `k logs -f test-54mgw`